# How can I change memory resources from within the DomU?

Tags: xen

For a certain job I sometimes need more memory in a DomU (CentOS 5).
The trigger for the start of the job are some conditions that I can only check within that DomU: The DomU is waiting for an upload. Once it is finished it needs to process the received data - best suited would be a ram-disk.

For this scenario I have set up the DomU with a memory setting of 1 GB min and 16 GB max.

Now I am trying to find an elegant way to resize the memory to max/min from within the DomU.

The first solution for this would be using ssh from DomU to all possible Dom0s and then trigger the "xm mem-set" commands there (with sudo).

I've read some things about the xen-store. Triggers were mentioned... So this makes me think that there should be a better way. It turned out that memory balloning would be a better way.

This should work within the DomU:

```
echo $((4096*1024*1024)) >/proc/xen/balloon
```

Should resize the memory to 4 GB.

But: cat /proc/xen/ballon says:

```
Current allocation:  2165536 kB
Requested target:    4192256 kB
Low-mem balloon:    14611680 kB
High-mem balloon:          0 kB
Driver pages:              0 kB
Xen hard limit:      2165536 kB
```

Now where does that xen hard limit come from?

Result is now that my DomU has 2 GB RAM.
xm list in Dom0 states that the DomU is still at 1 GB RAM...

What's going wrong here?
And yes - since the DomU-version is below 3.0.4 I added "mem=16G" as kernel-boot-parameter to my DomU.

With Dom0 SLES11 SP1 (XEN 4.0.1) and CentOS 5.6 DomU (still XEN 3.0.3?) the 
`echo 4G >/proc/xen/ballon` did not do anything first - but after I did some successful   `xm mem-sets` from the Dom0 (up to 16 GB - which worked), the */proc/xen/ballon* did work within the DomU, too.

Comment: you can use the balloon driver that xen has with min memory and max memory ... it's all dynamic and built in

Comment: Sounds interesting. So I just use echo 16GB (what unit do I have to use?) >/proc/xen/balloon from within the DomU an memory will just go up and vice versa?

Comment: Silviud: Can you post your comment as answer?

Comment: I've done some further testing today. It seem that both - the hypervisor-version and the supportet xen-version within the DomU seem to play a role here.

Comment: My initial try was with SLES10SP3 (XEN 3.2.3) and CentOS 5.5 (Xen DomU 3.0.3). There I got the above described effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the balloon driver that xen has with min memory and max memory ... it's all dynamic and built in

Comment: xen-balloning seems to be the right idea. But: It does not seem to work in all cases.