# if I have root password of Virtual Machine running on a host system , can I control host in any way

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machines

Our company gives a VM for each developer which is exclusive for them but doesnt give root access.

I am planning to ask for root password so I can install different softwares on the VM.

Just want to make sure, having a root password on VM doesnt give me any control on the host system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. It shouldn't give you any host access, assuming you're on one of the major virtualization suites (VMWare, KVM, Xen, etc.).

Comment: Assuming the root-password is not the same for all machines (including real ones)...on the other side, you might need to kick the IT department if that's the case.

Comment: Your answer is true in "normal" circumstances, but not when looking at exploits. So this is a matter of trust.

Answer (score 2):

There have been security problems with VMWare,KVM and XEN in the past, where you could get root on the VM-server if you were root in the VM.

**Update 1:**

For this reason I understand the unwillingness to pass root-passwords even for VMs.

An example for XEN is [CVE-2012-3515](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/55413) (this looks harmless on the third glance).

An example for KVM is [CVE-2011-2512](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2011-2512/).

An example for VMWare is [CVE-2012-1518](http://www.vmware.com/security/advisories/VMSA-2012-0007.html).

As there may be other unknown zero-day-exploits around one can never be sure...

**Update 2:**

root-access in XEN will give you control about [xen-ram-ballooning](https://serverfault.com/questions/257786/how-can-i-change-memory-resources-from-within-the-domu), too. This might have some bad side-effects on the VM-server-side, too (I tested this on a XEN Dom0: there are cases where the Dom0 does not tell the admin the truth any longer about the memory-consumtion of the DomU).

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If I have access to the virtual guest console, I can own the guest easily enough by _changing_ the root password, same as with a physical machine.

Comment: @MichaelHampton even in XEN console access might not give you the right to change the root-password. If using `pygrub` a grub-password should be active... but as I wrote this XEN-CVE looks harmless on the third glance. But it shows that there are exploits out there no normal user and admin can imagine.

Comment: And that's why we use [sVirt](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-sVirt.html).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Are you sure that SELinux would have helped against [CVE-2012-0029](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2012-0050.html)?

Comment: This is getting lengthy. Feel free to drop into chat if you want to discuss it further.